# How do I "Upgrade" a "DataVerse for Teams" environment to a regular environment?

Tags: common-data-service, power-platform, dataverse

When I try and "Upgrade" a "DataVerse for Teams" environment to a regular environment it errors out.

It produces the following error message.

"Failed to initiate upgrade of environment. Session Id: b15502de-5bad-43fc-a67b-9aca18XXXXXX"

I used the following documentation. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/about-teams-environment)

Could this be a permissions issue?

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to be a tenant admin to perform the upgrade, if you are not, this is the likely cause. Assuming you are a tenant admin, then the following details the exact process. which may help:

[Dataverse for Teams Upgrade Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/about-teams-environment#upgrade-process)